# Java Formatting String to Remove "0" in front of the variable

Tags: java, android, achartengine

Basically I am having some problem when trying to format the string I retrieved from database. Here is my nested for loop:

```
for (int count = 0; count < monthStr.length; count++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < trans_list.size(); i++) {
            if (count == Integer.parseInt(trans_list.get(i).getDate())) {
                expensesSeries.add(x[count], trans_list.get(i)
                        .getAmount());
            } 
            else{
                expensesSeries.add(x[count], 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically the getDate() will return string in these format: 01,02,03,04 and so on until 12. What I am trying to do is comparing the count which is 1-12, with the string I retrieved. Is there any way to remove the 0 in front of 01,02 from the string?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
    boolean setZero = true;
    String[] monthStr = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
            "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

    // Creating an XYSeries for Expenses
    XYSeries expensesSeries = new XYSeries("Expenses");
    for (int count = 1; count < 13; count++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < trans_list.size(); i++) {
            if (count == Integer.parseInt(trans_list.get(i).getDate())) {
                setZero = false;
                expensesSeries.add(count, trans_list.get(i)
                        .getAmount());
            } 
            if(setZero)
            {
                expensesSeries.add(count, 0);
                setZero = true;
            }       
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < monthStr.length; j++) {
        multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(j+1, monthStr[j]);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a problem with the code you posted? parseInt should get rid of the leading 0.

Comment: Is it? I thought it's because of the formatting causing my chart does not work properly.

Comment: what is wrong with your chart?  That is what your question should state :)

Comment: @RossDrew Lemme update my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Java Formatting String to Remove “0” in front of the variable**

`ParseInt` should be able to get an `int` from a `String` starting with 0 (as long as it precedes an int value) but if you need it for some other purpose not shown in this code just do a regular expression `replaceAll()` with the start character `^`

```
string.replaceAll("^0","");
```

and for multiple 0s, use `*` as well

```
string.replaceAll("^0*","");
```

**Specific Problem mentioned here**

Why the nested loop?  It looks like you want the contents of `trans_list` to be added as points via `expensesSeries`, with zero in places where there is no data. Just keep track of totals with an array:-

```
 int[] monthlyTotals = new int[12];
 for (int i=0; i<trans_list.size(); i++)
 {
   //Add item at index i trans_list at location i in chart
   int chartXIndex =  Integer.parseInt(trans_list.get(i).getdate());
   monthlyTotals[chartXIndex] += trans_list.get(i).getAmount();
 }
```

You now have an array that represents what you want on the chart so just loop to add them to the chart

```
for (int i=0; i<monthlyTotals.length; i++)
{
   expensesSeries.add(i, monthlyTotals[i]);
   multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, monthStr[i]); //combine your last loop as well
}
```

Nested looping can be confusing, avoid if possible.

Comment: I've updated my question. Please help me take a look when you free and yeah, you were right, it has nothing to do with the formatting :)

Comment: I've updated my codes again but this time around, let's say there is record for Mar and Jul and no record for Apr,May,Jun. It supposed to drop to 0 after Mar and went back to exact amount on Jul. But the output I've gotten is as the picture. Any ideas?

Comment: The zero values are missing, that's all, I've updated with a simplified answer

Comment: I am getting arrayIndexOutOfBoundException error message at the last line in the first for loop. Do you have any idea why is it so?

Comment: Thanks! With your answer and some amendments, it works perfectly now but I am still quite confused about some part of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt(...)` should do the trick. It looks like that it is already in your code, so I believe it works and maybe something else is causing the problem.
What is your problem here? Do you have an exception? Strange results?

I suggest you should change line

```
expensesSeries.add(x[count], trans_list.get(i).getAmount());
```

to

```
expensesSeries.add(Integer.parseInt(trans_list.get(i).getDate()) - 1, trans_list.get(i).getAmount());
```

(or better **assign** `Integer.parseInt(trans_list.get(i).getDate())` **to variable and reuse it** in if(...) and add(...)

Not sure if it will help, but x seems pointless and may cause some confusion.

**UPDATE**

I think, that introducing `boolean` variable is not necessary. Right now your code won't work properly. Imagine situation, where you do not have data with, lets say April (4). Then first `if` won't be processed, but second one also, so you won't have data (even with value 0) added to expendesSeries, and it will cause problem you are facing (no values for some of the months). Here I think is what you should do (edited your current code):

```
    String[] monthStr = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
            "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

    // Creating an XYSeries for Expenses
    XYSeries expensesSeries = new XYSeries("Expenses");
    for (int count = 1; count < 13; count++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < trans_list.size(); i++) {
            if (count == Integer.parseInt(trans_list.get(i).getDate())) {
                expensesSeries.add(count, trans_list.get(i)
                        .getAmount());
            } else {
                expensesSeries.add(count, 0);
            }       
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < monthStr.length; j++) {
        multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(j+1, monthStr[j]);
    }
```

Now it will fetch all months, then for every month it will fetch all transactions, and add 0 or some specific value to expensesSeries for each month. If that won't work I suggest using @RossDrew solution (it is simplified, more optimal and straightforward).

Comment: @kklys If I removed the x[], then how should I amend the code inside the else statement?

Comment: x[] is an array that only holds 0..11 values. these values (-1) are returned by getDate(). just use returned integer (parsed) and increment. the solution (imho) for main problem is under UPDATE

Comment: Would you mind to post the completed whole chunk of codes? Cause I am testing and debugging and the codes now are quite different from the original

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. It worsened the situation. I've put in the nearest code to the exact correct chart but there's still a slight problem. Let's say Jan and March got record, after Jan, at the Feb, it should be set to 0. Instead, it skips Feb and join Jan and March. Help me take a look when you free :)

Comment: not sure what is your sample data, but I updated my answer (according to your current code), maybe it will help

Comment: @kklys This is what I did but unfortunately, no luck :(

Comment: result is still the same (no data for months with 0 amount)? or is there another problem with my code? I see code from another answer worked for you, great!